# when zoom browser floats moves

Tags: html, css

i have code:

```
<div class="container">
  <li class="block2"></li>
  <ul class="posts first">
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="posts second">
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
    <li class="block"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and css:

```
container{
  width:940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:40px;
  background:grey;
}
.container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.block{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width:216px;
  height:186px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 22px;
  list-style: none;
}
.block2{
  float:right;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  clear:both;
  width:217px;
  height:603px;
  list-style:none;
}
.posts{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.first .block:nth-child(3n+1){
  margin-left:0px;
  clear:left;
}
.second .block:nth-child(4n+1){
  margin-left:0px;
  clear:left;
}
```

It is ok when browser zoom is 100%, but when i zoom browser window to 25%, floats going move. What i doing wrong and how can i fix it? Code on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/92j5yr6c/1/

i need something like this on 25% zoom [link](http://postimg.org/image/p5yjpc4r5/)

Comment: Not sure what you expected to happen? The browser is a fixed width; when you zoom in the contents expand, but the browser is still the same width.

Comment: You might want to look into using percentages instead of pixels for your widths.

Comment: There's nothing to fix, because there's nothing wrong. Can you explain what kind of layout you would like to have? And why would you want to zoom the browser size? I'd recommend against needing to do that at all.

Comment: I want that my blocks are not moving from his seat when changing browser zoom

Comment: @Lee something like this [link](http://postimg.org/image/p5yjpc4r5) and [link](http://postimg.org/image/pu7e8a3gx)

Comment: you can use `vw` if you don't want the blocks to move. obviously that would mess up with responsiveness. Your best option is to wrap the whole body with a `wrapper` div and then  use `margin:auto;` to keep the contents centered. Finally use percentages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to tackle this with the given code is IMHO:

1) Adjust the error in your CSS (I'm assuming that was only a copy error for your JsFiddle) - your container-class is missing the period to make it actually a class. Change
`container{` to `.container{`

and 2)
Change from `border` to `outline` (I assume this is acceptable), since borders tend to remain above "just a fraction of a pixel" wide, they end up adding up to more width than is available. And an outline doesn't grow the object, it just sits on top.

works for me:
https://jsfiddle.net/c0hfopug/

Comment: Glad to hear it. But, in general, you might be interested in looking into responsive design practices. This was just a solution that works for this specific purpose. Have fun :)

Comment: maybe you can help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103716/when-zoom-browser-window-text-block-moving